# Combining lists based on a key value

Tags: python, list, cisco

I have a script that has multiple show commands and I would like to merge them into a single list based off the interface value

```
from MY_ATH import ME
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import json

#Enter in the IP of the switch, username and password
IP = input('IP of switch: ')
username = ME['username']
password = ME['password']

SW = {
    'ip':   IP,
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**SW)

#This script has hardcoded voice vlan info

#does this command and looks at the structured data
interfaces = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces switchport', use_textfsm=True)
#cdp = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces switchport', use_textfsm=True)
#cdp2 = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces description', use_textfsm=True)
#print(json.dumps(interfaces, indent=2))
#print(json.dumps(cdp3, indent=2))

interface_list = []
for interface in interfaces:
    result={}
    result["interface"] = interface['interface']
    result["admin_mode"] = interface['admin_mode']
    result["access_vlan"] = interface['access_vlan']
    result["voice_vlan"] = interface['voice_vlan']
    result["trunking_vlans"] = interface['trunking_vlans']

    interface_list.append(result)

print (json.dumps(interface_list, indent=2))

interfaces1 = net_connect.send_command('show interfaces description', use_textfsm=True)
#print(json.dumps(interfaces1, indent=2))

interface_list1 = []
for interface in interfaces1:
    result={}
    result["interface"]=interface['port']
    result["descrip"] = interface['descrip']

    interface_list1.append(result)

print (json.dumps(interface_list1, indent=2))

interfaces2 = net_connect.send_command('show lldp neighbors detail', use_textfsm=True)
#print(json.dumps(interfaces2, indent=2))
interface_list2 = []
for interface in interfaces2:
    result={}
    result["interface"]=interface['local_interface']
    result["neighbor"] = interface['neighbor']
    interface_list2.append(result)

print (json.dumps(interface_list2, indent=2))
print(interface_list)
print(interface_list1)
print(interface_list2)

for key in interface_list:
    print (key)
for key in interface_list1:
    print (key)
for key in interface_list2:
    print (key)
```

The printed info I get is this:

```
{'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': '2122', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/3', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/4', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/5', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/6', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '1035', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/7', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': '2122', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/8', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': '2122', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/9', 'admin_mode': 'trunk', 'access_vlan': '1', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['340,503,1001,1035,1500,2122,2430,3216,3350']}
{'interface': 'Gi0/10', 'admin_mode': 'trunk', 'access_vlan': '1', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['503,1001,1115,1175,1177,2020,2122,2430,3216,3227']}
{'interface': 'Vl1', 'descrip': ''}
{'interface': 'Vl1001', 'descrip': ''}
{'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/1'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/2'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/3', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/3'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/4', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/4'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/5', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/5'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/6', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/6'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/7', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/7'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/8', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/8'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/9', 'descrip': 'to 501_2nd_10.0.1.20.ne.gov'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/10', 'descrip': 'to 0.0.1.20'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/9', 'neighbor': '501_2nd_10.0.1.20.ne.gov'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'neighbor': 'SEP08CCA7845AC3.nebraska.gov'}
{'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'neighbor': ''}
{'interface': 'Gi0/7', 'neighbor': ''}
{'interface': 'Gi0/5', 'neighbor': ''}
```

I would like to merge all this into something like this:

```
{'interface': 'Gi0/1',
 'admin_mode': 'static access',
 'access_vlan': '3216',
 'voice_vlan': 'none',
 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL'],
 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/1',
 'neighbor': ''}
```

Comment: How do you decide which values are used in the final output dictionary? Why is it `'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/1'` and `'neighbor': ''` instead of `'descrip': ''` and `'neighbor': '501_2nd_10.0.1.20.ne.gov'`?

Comment: He wants to combine all the separate dictionaries by interface. The example given is for interface `Gi0/1`. But he wants it for each of the interfaces listed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have a dictionary with the interface as the key and an inner dictionary as the value that you update with each new result for that interface.

```
outputs = [
    # Only the 'Gi0/1' and 'Gi0/2' interfaces are used in this example.
    {'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']},
    {'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': '2122', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL']},
    {'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/1'},
    {'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/2'},
    {'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'neighbor': 'SEP08CCA7845AC3.nebraska.gov'},
    {'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'neighbor': ''},
]

results = {}

for output in outputs:
    interface = output['interface']
    try:
        interface_dict = results[interface]
    except KeyError:
        # This interface not in results yet. Add it.
        interface_dict = {}
        results[interface] = interface_dict
    # Update interface_dict with new values from output
    interface_dict.update(output)

print(results)
```

Where `results` looks like this:

```
{
    'Gi0/1': {'interface': 'Gi0/1', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': 'none', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL'], 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/1', 'neighbor': ''},
    'Gi0/2': {'interface': 'Gi0/2', 'admin_mode': 'static access', 'access_vlan': '3216', 'voice_vlan': '2122', 'trunking_vlans': ['ALL'], 'descrip': 'Interface Gi0/2', 'neighbor': 'SEP08CCA7845AC3.nebraska.gov'}
}
```

In your script, you could save all the outputs in a list and do the combining at the end as I have shown above.

Another way would be to create a function that takes the result dictionary and the one to combine into it, and does it every time you get more data. This would be useful if you have a lot of data and don't want to hold on to it until the end.